# Does SELECT * create additional overhead even when you want all columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have read that `SELECT *` is typically undesirable in that it creates additional overhead. Is this the case if you want to retrieve all columns?

I have a extremely badly performing queries, which is made up of nested 'SELECT *' queries. In all cases I do want all the columns returned to me though...

Comment: If someone adds more columns to the table, then your query will ultimately use them which then creates additional and unforseen overhead.

Comment: Zach, have you tested it? I have not but have always assumed that there was at least _some_, even if negligible, amount of overhead as it requires SQL Server to go discover what columns exist before proceeding. It is not something that would contribute to a single instance of a query taking a long time, but could add up (if it truly exists) over _many_ repeated calls when looking at overall application performance.

Comment: I haven't tested it... I'm looking for places where there could potentially be performance bottlenecks. I don't think `SELECT *` is one, but thought I would check in case

Comment: For the most part I only use SELECT * on subqueries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly answering your question, no there is no additional overhead when you want all columns returned.  But it is undesirable as you mentioned. I do not want to reiterate why it is undesirable as most of the points are discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).